# If i use jquery in projects then should i keep "firequery" installed?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

If i use jquery in projects then should i keep "firequery" installed?

http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Would it be helpful?

Comment: What do you mean, "should keep it installed"? It's a browser extension, what's the difference?

Comment: I'm going to call BS on this question. This user has a history of poor questions/spamming random questions. -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In firequery

- jQuery expressions are intelligently presented in Firebug Console and DOM inspector
- attached jQuery data are first class citizens
- elements in jQuery collections are highlighted on hover
- jQuerify: enables you to inject jQuery into any page

If you want to use these features then it is helpful else no need.
I would suggest you to keep because there is no drawback to keep.

Comment: can i run my jquey code temporarily in no.conflict mode using this plugin.?

Comment: Yes, you can. I have just defined var t$ = jQuery.noConflict() in google.com and check t$("#logo"). it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect extension to embed jQuery into Chrome Console as simple as you can imagine. This extension also indocates if jQuery has been already embeded into page.

This extension used to embed jQuery into any page you want. It allows to use jQuery in the console shell (You can invoke Chrome console by "Ctrl+Shift+j").

To embed jQuery into selected tab click on extention button.

*LINK* to extension:
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gbmifchmngifmadobkcpijhhldeeelkc